# What is the proper syntax for accessing a struct variable?

Tags: swift, struct

What is the proper syntax for access a member struct variable? I'm currently trying like this:

```
struct one {
    var name:String = "Ric"
    var address:String = "Lee"
}

one.name
```

But the last line produces the error:

> 'one.Type' does not have a member named 'name'

How can I access the variable on my struct?

Comment: Did you forget to instantiate a member of your struct?

Comment: Note the error says "one.Type". This should be an immediate clue into how the compiler is trying to resolve the expression.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like you defined a struct, but didn't create an instance of it. If you create an instance, you can access its name and address properties.

```
struct one {
    var name: String = "Ric"
    var address: String = "Lee"
}
var x = one()
x.name
```

It may be confusing because you can set default values in the definition, which may make it look like you are instantiating something.

Comment: and by swift naming conventions, type names should be in title case, so this should be `struct One {`.

Comment: Understood.  One().name -- ok.

Comment: remember that `One` is the type. If you want an instance, you would say, e.g., `let one = One()`. The capitalization is just a convention, but it's a good habit.

Comment: @FrederickC.Lee: notice that One().name creates an instance of `One`, reads its `name` property, then releases (i.e. trashes) that instance. If what you are trying to achieve is having constants, then you should look into `static` and `let` (immutable) properties

Answer (score 5):

When you declare a struct, in order to use it you have to create an instance. The `one` struct is a type, just like `Int` is a type and in order to use it you have to create a variable of `Int` type:

```
var myInt:Int = 10
```

Similarly, once you define a struct, you can create instances of that struct and assign to a variable:

```
var myStruct = one()
```

at that point you are able to access to instance properties and methods:

```
println(myStruct.name)
```

If instead you don't need an instance, then you should declare properties and methods as `static`:

```
struct one {
    static var name: String = "Ric"
    static var address: String = "Lee"
}
```

and that's the only case when you can reference properties and invoke methods using the *type* and not an *instance of the type*:

```
println(one.name)
```

*Side note*: by convention, classes and struct (and more generally any type) should be named with the first character in upper case.